# glassfish v3 - update all pakages via command line on linux

Tags: command-line-interface, glassfish, update

Does anyone know how to do this?  I just want a one-shot command to "update everything" over the command line?  This is for a remote server so it must be over the command line.

I used:

```
$ sudo pkg list -u
```

to see  the list of packages that are out of date, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to say, "ok, update them".

I have scoured the web for clues, but to no avail :(

This is classic Sun Solaris-type patching that is the exact reason I am now on Linux.

Please help!! Thanks :)

Jamie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone else reads this:

`sudo pkg image-update`

and I guess you will need a glassfish restart after that...!

I actually [found the answer here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19226-01/820-7692/ghhmw/index.html).